# Getting 'failed to find geo_point field [pin.location]' error using elastic seatch and angular 4

Tags: angular, elasticsearch

I am getting this error failed to find geo_point field [pin.location]' error using elastic seatch and angular 4 when i try to call elastic search API using the Angular 4

My Angular code 
  fullTextSearch(_index, _type, _field, _queryText): any {

```
return this.client.search({
  index: _index,
  body: {
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
              "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "150km",
                    "location" : {
                      "lat" : -70.34,
                      "lon" : 40.12 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

}

My elasticsearch _search API data

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "dev_ll_user",
                "_type": "user",
                "_id": "2243534dfsgdfg56456gy54675",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "location": {
                        "lat": 40.12,
                        "lon": -71.34
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "dev_ll_user",
                "_type": "user",
                "_id": "12f7b1c5-2f2d-4841-a8ba-9bc46de3f73f",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "location": {
                        "lat": 40.12,
                        "lon": -71.34
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am getting this Error

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to find geo_point field [location]","index_uuid":"vwW0z7FLT7-nMOMl0-P5Hw","index":"dev_ll_user"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"dev_ll_user","node":"G2sZhDbgQ02V1hay3rzoWg","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to find geo_point field [location]","index_uuid":"vwW0z7FLT7-nMOMl0-P5Hw","index":"dev_ll_user"}}]},"status":400}
```

Comment: Well, it seems some of your documents in the index dev_ll_user don't have a location field, or have one which is not of type geo_point.

Comment: @JBNizet I am having type: user also i have added this but still having this issue..

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/dev_ll_user` ?

Comment: @Val getting this "location": {  "type": "geo_point"  }...

Comment: Why do you mention an error on `pin.location` when your field is called `location` and the error at the bottom states `location` as well?

Comment: ok @Val can u please suggest some example codes.. i am stucking with this.. need working code example

Comment: according to your mapping + data + query, it should work. Not sure what's wrong here. Are you sure that your `_index` variable contains the right index, i.e. `dev_ll_user` ?

Comment: yes @Val when i change the pin.location to location returning success response but value is null

Comment: Please provide your full mapping and some sample data so that we can recreate the issue. Something is clearly off somewhere

Comment: @val i have changed my data structure to pin { location } to location { } that working as expected... Thanks for the suggestions u saved my day... :)

Comment: Good, glad you figured it out!